# To find the maximum number of order count that occur in any 1 hour of the day from the database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a food selling website in which there is order table which record the order of every user.It column for user id ,user name,orderid ,timestamp of order.I want to know the maximum number of order that has been made in any one hour span through out the day.Give me any formula for this,or any algorithm or any sql queries for these.

Comment: Can you pls share code which you have tried?

Comment: There are many different "flavours" of SQL, please tag the DBMS you are using to get the best answers

Comment: i am using mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL server:

```
with CTE as
(
select cast(t1.timestamp  as date) as o_date, datepart(hh, t1.timestamp) as o_hour, count(*) as orders
from MyTable t1
group by cast(t1.timestamp  as date), datepart(hh, t1.timestamp)
)
select o_date, o_hour, orders
from CTE
where orders = (select max(orders) from CTE)
```

Oracle

```
with CTE as
(
select to_char(t1.timestamp, 'YYYYMMDD') as o_date, to_char(t1.timestamp, 'HH24') as o_hour, count(*)
from MyTable t1
group by to_char(t1.timestamp, 'YYYYMMDD'), to_char(t1.timestamp, 'HH24')
)
select o_date, o_hour, orders
from CTE
where orders = (select max(orders) from CTE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get count by day and hour like this

For SQL

```
SELECT TOP 1
    COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY DATEPART(day, [column_date]), DATEPART(hour, [column_date])
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

For MySQL

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(*)
FROM myTable
GROUP BY HOUR(column_date), DAY(column_date)
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Which dbms is this for? (It's not ANSI SQL, and the question has no dbms spocified.)